# nuxtServerInit in Modules mode does not run

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` in Universal mode and i'm trying to run `nuxtServerInit()` in one of my store actions, however it is not running.

In the docs it says...

> If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary
>   module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to
>   chain your module actions from there.

However I don't quite understand what you need to do in order to make this work. Also if you need to use the primary module, then why would you need to use the module mode at all? Then you should just need to use the Classic mode.

**store/posts.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    loadedPosts:[]
});

export const getters = {
    get(state){
        return state
    }
};

export const mutations = {
    setPosts(state, payload){
        state.loadedPosts = payload;
    }
};

export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit ({commit}){
        const {data} = await axios.get('somedata')
        console.log('I cannot see this comment');
        commit('setPosts', data.results)
    }
};
```

Comment: so.. it does say that you need to have that function in `./store/index.js` and you're putting in `./store/posts.js` ... no wonder it does not work  it really needs to be in the `index.js` file, I have several store files, and the index only has that function!

Comment: How do you chain it to other parts of your store modules? If this is the action to get "someData" do you use other methods to get a list of "Cars", "Boats", Motorbikes etc, therefor you have a big list of nuxtServerInit in the index.js file

Comment: added as an answer... might be better with an example 

Comment: @ottz0: for last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61861942/vue-js-undefined-in-nested-object-with-v-for): you should use as `product.price.planMonthly["rrp"]` because you have quotes in key

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the documentation, you really need to have that function in the `index.js` file inside the `store` folder, which will not work otherwise.

here's an example of a production NuxtJs universal application with the `./store/index.js` only with that file, you can easily call other stores methods by prefixing them with the file name, as the example shows `auth/setAuth`

[image]

Comment: Thank you...got it...What if you need to make several nuxtServerInits? So on init I need to getBlogPosts, getProductReviews, getProducts, you just use 1 action and 1 nuxtServerInit and then have several methods inside of nuxtServerInit?

Comment: you can only have one `nuxtServerInit` function, but inside you can call whatever methods you want for all external store files, for example, you can have several lines of `commit()` and fire them simultaneously to perform some action on each store file you need

Comment: what's `process.server` for? Isn't `nuxtServerInit` only called on server?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the problem that nuxtServerInit was not called. The reason was in nuxt.config.js where ssr was set to false.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  // ssr: false,  <-- Remove or out comment the line

  /*
   ** Nuxt target
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
   */
  target: 'server',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
  }
}
```